# MvvmCross and Xamarin.Forms.Wpf

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin app using MvvmCross. I need to add desktop support so I am trying to use Xamarin.Forms for that. Unfortunately I failed with the official [TipCalc sample](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarin-forms-version)
I've added the Wpf project to [my fork of samples sources](https://github.com/mashbrno/MvvmCross-Samples/commit/2741a980d9425485b9f662a4796198522a35f84b).

The problem is that class `App` in WPF project derives from `MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views.MvxApplication` which does not implements `IMvxApplication`.

Comment: did you install the `MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Wpf` and `MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf` packages on your wpf project ?

Comment: also the MainWindow must inherit from `MvxFormsWindowsPage` on the cs page. Remember to always check the [Playground](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground) project, is the most updated one with the last changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys! Take a few hours sleep and checking the [Playground](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground) project solved my problem. There are multiple `App` classes - first in `Core` project which is `MvxApplication`, second in `Forms.UI` project and third in `Forms.WPF`.